# The number of bits needed to address 64KB

Tags: algorithms

[image]

Introduction to computer science Level 109
I don’t understand the question

Comment: I don't understand the answer. $64 \times 210$ is not $216$ and $\log_2 216$ is not $16$. Also, why is the "number of needed bits" expressed in bits itself? It should be a pure number.

Comment: I also don’t understand

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently the victim of poor typography.

Number of bits = log<sub>2</sub>(64 * 2<sup>10</sup>) = log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>16</sup>) = 16.

Does that make it clear?

Nevertheless, this is the wrong forum for this question. This forum is for computer science educators.

Comment: [This forum is for questions and answers in the realm of computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour). [As defined for COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For *students, researchers and practitioners*.